# Number of ordered pairs $(f(x), g(x))$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

**Problem :**

Given two continuous function $f(x), g(x)$ which satisfies :

$$f(x)+g(x)=x^3+x \\ f(x)g(x)=x^4$$

Find a number of ordered pairs $(f(x), g(x))$

---

I think the answer is $16$.

Consider quadratic equation which has its roots $f(x), g(x)$ :

$$t^2-(x^3+x)t+x^4=0.$$

From quadratic root formula, I got two functions :

$$f_1(x)=\max(x,x^3) \\
f_2(x) = \min(x,x^3)$$

and both $f_1$ and $f_2$ change its behavior $3$ times (Since cubic equation $x^3=x$ has three distinct roots),

both $f_1$ and $f_2$ can be divided into four parts $(-\infty, -1), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (1,\infty).$

So, I can choose the function $2^4=16$. Is this valid?

Comment: I agree with the conclusion "can be divided into four parts ... so result is $2^4=16$" but not so much with the presentation with $f_1,f_2,\min,\max$. Because $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^3$ everywhere is valid, yet not so much representable with your $f_1,f_2$.

Comment: I agree with zwim. Your ideas are correct, but your explanation is severely lacking. What you know from the quadratic is that for each fixed $x$ either $f(x) = x^3, g(x) = x$ or vice versa. By continuity, $f$ can switch from being $x^3$ to being $x$ only where $x^3 = x$. That gives the four intervals on each of which $f(x) = x^3$ everywhere, or $f(x) = x$ everywhere. Thus there are $2$ choices for $f$ on each interval, or $2^4$ choices total. $f$ determines $g$, so there are $2^4$ pairs.